# Can we add any right hand side of these equations so that these can't be solved?

Tags: linear-algebra

for the system of equations$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 2 & 0 & 3\\3 & 1 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\\7\end{bmatrix}$$ can we replace the right hand side by any vector so that this can't be solved ? And how can we do this ? Regards

Comment: This question is set up to intentionally trick you into guessing and checking. How do you know when a system of equations is consistent (i.e. can be solved)?

Comment: I got this. If the RHS becomes $[ 2 5 2]^T$ then it can't be solved